# Hygieia JIRA Collector NullPointerException

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api, hygieia

I tried to include our JIRA to Hygieia Dashboard. But I always get a NPE in Jira-Collector.

This is the log-file:

```
hygieia-jira | 2016-05-10 08:27:06,304 ERROR c.c.d.c.s.FeatureDataClientSetupImpl - Unexpected error in Jira paging request of java.lang.NullPointerException
hygieia-jira | [null]
```

And the docker-compose settings:

```
hygieia-jira-feature-collector:
image: hygieia-jira-feature-collector:latest
container_name: hygieia-jira
volumes:
 - ./logs:/hygieia/logs
links:
 - mongodb:mongo
 - hygieia-api
environment:
  - JIRA_BASE_URL=https://our-jira.com/tracker/base64
  - JIRA_CREDENTIALS=b2ZhMmFidDpibsdfGlkbWlsdfzYWfsfdub37527lpbmc=
  - JIRA_ISSUE_TYPE_ID=267
  - JIRA_SPRINT_DATA_FIELD_NAME=customfield_14290
  - JIRA_EPIC_FIELD_NAME=customfield_15590
```

Comment: It seems taht you have forgotten the value for the collector, after ":" you should add the value, shouldn't you?

Comment: You mean here 'hygieia-jira-feature-collector:' ? Then no. This is like the starting tag ;)

Comment: Yeah! I ment that, but i was just wondering. Sorry, i can't help here. :)